# How to count the sum of the numeric found in a string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to count sum of the numbers found in a string, not digits. For example, there are string = "abc12df34", and the answer must be 46 (12+34), not 10. Also maybe negative numbers for string = "abc10gf-5h1" answer must be 6. I can not understand how to implement this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RegEx approach:

```
string input = "abc10gf-5h1";
int result = Regex.Matches(input, "-?[0-9]+").Cast<Match>().Sum(x =>int.Parse(x.Value));
```

Answer (score -1):

While the above answer is elegant, it's not really something to understand what to do or how to approach the problem. Here is another, more explicit solution.

In words, you iterate through your string, collect digits as long as there are any, if you find a nondigit, your number is finished, you convert the number to integer and sum it up, clear the number string. The same you do if you find the end of the string. On the next found digit you start collecting digits again.

This algorithm will fail on any number larger than than 10 digits in multiple ways (as the other answer will also), but this is just for demonstration anyway.

```
    string input = "abc10gf-5-1h1";

    var number = new char[10];
    int numberlength = 0;
    int pos = 0;

    int sum = 0;
    while (pos < input.Length)
    {
        char c = input[pos++];
        if (char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            number[numberlength++]=c;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (numberlength > 0)
            {
                sum += int.Parse(new String(number, 0, numberlength));
                numberlength = 0;
            }
            if (c=='-')
                number[numberlength++]=c;
        }
    }

    if (numberlength > 0)
            sum += int.Parse(new String(number, 0, numberlength));

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: fails at `char.IsDigit` in case of digits of other cultures. e.g. thai digits `string input = "abc10gf-5๑h1";` ( `๑` equals `1`). I would use `if ("0123456789".Contains(c))` instead.

Comment: fails at double use of `-` character. e.g. `string input = "abc10gf--5-1h1";`